# Strange Spinner. How to fix it?

Tags: android

This is my code to populate the Spinner. It looks strange and ugly.

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final List<String> result) {
        System.out.println("Result: " + result);
        final SpinnerAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(SearchTopActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, new String[]{"test1", "test2"});
        countrySpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/countrySpinner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

[image]

**How to fix it like this**

[image]

Comment: (SearchTopActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, new String[]{"test1", "test2"}) change this android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item to android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item

Comment: No, I want to use dropdown item. The "Saturn" sample uses "simple_spinner_dropdown_item" too.

Comment: Do as `Dheeresh Singh` says. Use `simple_spinner_dropdown_item` at `adapter.setDropDownViewResource()`

Comment: Got it! Set it two times: once in constructor and once in setDropDownViewResource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(SearchTopActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, new String[]{"test1", "test2"})` 
change this

```
android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item to android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item
```

refer 
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-spinner.html

Answer (score 2):

I think that happens because of the layout file you use. Try to use:

```
android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item
```

Answer (score 0):

**TRY THIS**

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final List<String> result) {
        System.out.println("Result: " + result);
    final String[] test = new String[] { "test1", "test2" };

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, test);
    countrySpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
}
and xml as::

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/countrySpinner"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I just wrote my own adapter by extending   BaseAdapter and implementing    SpinnerAdapter. Also I wrote my one item layout :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvParticipantSpinnerName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And the spinner behave normally.