# Customizing Spinner Android?

Tags: java, android

I have spinner and code `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item`.
But I get weird height like this:

[image]

I want to have `dropdown_items` like they are by default but also I don't want to have weird height on the main screen.

Comment: You've just missed this question 30 minutes ago http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10893460/strange-spinner-how-to-fix-it/10893503#10893503

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `adapter.setDropDownViewResource(int resId)` method to use a specific layout for the dropdown box (not the elements)

As seen [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-spinner.html)